# Got proxy authentication error in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication, http-proxy

This is my code for News API, I got an error for the proxy settings, which might not be in a correct way I guess. I need help in resolving Authentication error to set proxy.

Code:

```
from newsapi import NewsApiClient
from requests.auth import HTTPProxyAuth

# Init
api = NewsApiClient(api_key='b6d976f8d22a4dfsdfgdfgsfASAS453410c37')


http_proxy  = "https://7031:Welcome1567@58.2.64.2:31"
https_proxy = "http://7031:Welcome1567@58.2.64.2:31"
ftp_proxy   = "https://7031:Welcome1567@58.2.64.2:31"
proxyDict = { 
        "http"  : http_proxy, 
        "https" : https_proxy, 
        "ftp"   : ftp_proxy
        }

auth = HTTPProxyAuth('username', 'mypassword')
# /v2/top-headlines
top_headlines = newsapi.get_top_headlines(q='bitcoin',
                                          sources='bbc-news,the-verge',
                                          category='business',
                                          language='en',
                                          country='us')

# /v2/everything
all_articles = newsapi.get_everything(q='bitcoin',
                                      sources='bbc-news,the-verge',
                                      domains='bbc.co.uk,techcrunch.com',
                                      from_parameter='2017-12-01',
                                      to='2017-12-12',
                                      language='en',
                                      sort_by='relevancy',
                                      page=2)

# /v2/sources
sources = newsapi.get_sources()
```

Error I got from output is:
Output:

```
File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 502, in send

ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='newsapi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v2/top-headlines?q=bitcoin&sources=bbc-news%2Cthe-verge&language=en&country=us&category=business (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 authenticationrequired',)))
```